# MVC5 throw HttpException of 401 returns 500

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

I'm trying to throw an 401 HttpException but application always returns 500 instead of 401. This is not happening when I throw other 4XX error.

```
    public ActionResult Error401()
    {
         throw new HttpException(401, "Unauthorized");
    }
```

I'm trying to create custom error pages for 500, 404, 403, 400 and 401. For all errors except 401 I obtain the correct page, for 401 I get in browser 500 error and 500 custom error page.

```
   <system.web>
       <customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite" defaultRedirect="~/CustomErrors/InternalServerError.aspx">
            <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/CustomErrors/InternalServerError.aspx" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/CustomErrors/NotFound.aspx" />
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/CustomErrors/Forbidden.aspx" />
            <error statusCode="400" redirect="~/CustomErrors/BadRequest.aspx" />
            <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/CustomErrors/Unauthorized.aspx" />
        </customErrors>
   </system.web>



public class ErrorHandleAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled == false)
        {
            return;
        }

        object exception = filterContext.Exception;
        int httpStatusCode = (exception as HttpException).GetHttpCode();

        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = httpStatusCode;
    }
}
```

Any ideas of other solutions to return the right custom page for 401?

Thanks

Comment: Have you registered your custom error attribute?

Comment: Yes it is registered, I get all custom error pages beside 401.

Answer (score -1):

You should try to do this

```
public ActionResult Error401()
{
   return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Forbidden");
}
```

Then you don't need to throw an exception every time, because it is more expensive.

Comment: This seems to be a solution, but it will not go through my ErrorHandle filter. It's also equivalent with - return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Unauthorized");
And to return a custom error page it needs some more configuration in web.config in httpErrors (IIS) section.
I would need something that goes through errorhandle filter.